# Take the first command line argument and pass the rest

Tags: bash

Example:

`check_prog hostname.com /bin/check_awesome -c 10 -w 13`

```
check_remote -H $HOSTNAME -C "$ARGS"
#To be expanded as
check_remote -H hostname.com -C "/bin/check_awesome -c 10 -w 13"
```

I hope the above makes sense. The arguments will change as I will be using this for about 20+ commands. Its a odd method of wrapping a program, but it's to work around a few issues with a few systems we are using here (gotta love code from the 70s).

The above could be written in Perl or Python, but Bash would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use [shift](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html)

shift is a shell builtin that operates on the positional parameters. Each time you invoke shift, it "shifts" all the positional parameters down by one. $2 becomes $1, $3 becomes $2, $4 becomes $3, and so on

example:

```
$ function foo() { echo $@; shift; echo $@; } 
$ foo 1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm `echo $1
shift
echo $*
` is a example of how to use shift for future people searching for this, run it like `./script.sh cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 cmd4` and it will set $1 to cmd1 and the rest will be cmd2 cmd3 cmd4 like I wanted

Comment: And `$#` is reduced by 1 unless it's already 0.  You can also give `shift` a numeric argument to shift by more than one place.

Comment: @user554005: You should almost always use `echo "$@"` instead of `echo $*` or `echo "$*"` since the unquoted form and the quoted `$*` form "flatten" the arguments which is usually not wanted.

Comment: So typical use would be `SOME_VAR=$1; shift; some_cmd "$*"`. Now `some_cmd` is passed args 2..n. Works great... Thanks!

Comment: @BradParks when passing filenames as arguments that will be read by another command, and if the filenames contain spaces, I think you want `SOME_VAR=$1; shift; some_cmd "$@"` because `"$@"` ensures that escaped spaces will be passed with a backslash prefixing the space. `"$*"` will drop the `\ ` character (or flatten the filename, as described above)

Answer (score 45):

As a programmer I would strongly recommend against `shift` because operations that modify the state can affect large parts of a script and make it harder to understand, modify, and debug:sweat_smile:. You can instead use the following:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

all_args=("$@")
first_arg="$1"
second_args="$2"
rest_args=("${all_args[@]:2}")

echo "${rest_args[@]}"
```

Comment: I’d strongly recommend against storing a list of arguments in a simple string variable and/or expanding variables without double-quotes (like `REST_ARGS` here). Use an array (like `ALL_ARGS`) and expand it with `[@]` and double-quotes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson can you rewrite the `bash` snippet with your recommendation or write a different snippet? I'd very much like to understand it more and use it in some `bash` scripts I'm working on right now. Thanks in advance and keep up the good work!

Comment: I've edited it to show my recommended form. Storing lists of arguments as strings loses the distinction between multiple arguments vs single arguments containing spaces; expanding them without double-quotes will split on *all* spaces (including those that were originally within arguments), and also expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard. For example, if you run the original as `./script "foo" "bar" "six * nine"`, it would print "six <list of files in the current directory> nine".

Comment: I also recommend lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid conflicts with the various all-caps names with special meanings. Oh, and [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out problematic quoting and other common mistakes.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson now I can write better BASH scripts and people who follow my answer won't repeat my mistakes.

Comment: And [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is an excellent tool. It can save a lot of engineering time and can run in CI too. Thanks @GordonDavisson again for this great tip ^_^.

Answer (score 33):

Adapting [Abdullah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59126818/41283) a bit:

```
your_command "$1" "${@:2}"
```

Tested on Bash (v3.2 and v5.1) and Zsh (v5.8)